# EOFError: unexpected end of input; is count incorrect or file otherwise damaged? Don't know how to fix

Tags: python, word2vec

I am having this issue with my code when trying to run this code segment in Jupyter Notebook, can anyone give me an idea as to how to fix it? I am trying to use the word2vec continuous bag model, and this code segment is not running due to this error:

> EOFError: unexpected end of input; is count incorrect or file otherwise damaged?

Here is the code segment:

```
cbow_output = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('Downloads/vectors.txt' , binary=False)
cbow_output.most_similar(positive=['virus'])
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's the error you'd get if the top of the file declares more vectors than follow.

Where did you get the `vectors.txt` file you're loading, and are you sure it downloaded completely, without being cut-off at any point? Can you try re-downloading it?

If you're on a Linux/MacOS/Unixy system, you can do `head -1 vectors.txt` in a command-shell to see the first line, which will declare both the dimensionality & count-of-vectors expected. You can do `wc -l vectors.txt` to report a count of the lines.

If the count of the lines isn't exactly one more than the reported count, it's missing some lines – and you should try to re-download a complete copy.

If the file is irrecoverably truncated, you could use the `limit` option to only read a subset of the vectors that are there. So if `wc` reported, say more than 100000 vectors, you could load the 1st 100000 using the optional `limit=100000` argument to `.load_word2vec_format()` (even if it originally had, and declared up-top, more vectors).

Answer (score 0):

You should read the vector file. The first line consists of 2 numbers. The first one is the total lines of the file and the second one is the dimension. Unfortunately, the number of lines is incorrect so you should decrease the number by one. e.g. if the first is 2196017 300 you should replace it with 2196016 300.